# Getting names/coordinates of stopovers on transit route via google Maps Api

Tags: google-maps, maps, here-api, map-directions

I am trying to find out the names/coords of stops being made on a transit route via googleMaps js API
I working with the directionsService function in travelMode transit, here’s a example output:

```
{
 "arrival_stop": {},
 "arrival_time": {},
 "departure_stop": {},
 "departure_time": {},
 "headsign": "Green Westbound to Bankhead Station",
 "line": {},
 "num_stops": 1
}
```

When a route via transit goes from a to b with a stop at c, directionsService tells me the number of stops (num_stops) but not the names or coords of them. In the native iOS App it does. Is this feature not supported in the Web API yet or am i missing out on something?

Has anybody else been working with another routing service, supporting this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the [here API](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/public_transit/public-transit-routing) can provide these information:

```
curl \
-X GET \
-H 'Content-Type: *' \
--get 'https://transit.api.here.com/v3/route.json' \
--data-urlencode 'dep=52.521504,13.41126' \
--data-urlencode 'arr=52.515829,13.45395' \
--data-urlencode 'time=2018-11-19T07:30:00' \
--data-urlencode 'app_id=devportal-demo-20180625' \
--data-urlencode 'app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ' \
--data-urlencode 'routing=tt'
```

Will return a json like this (excerpt)

```
"Journey": {
"duration": "PT6M",
"Stop": [
{
    "dep": "2018-11-19T07:51:00",
    "Stn": {
    "id": "vbb_900100704",
    "name": "S+U Alexanderplatz [U5]",
    "x": 13.41311,
    "y": 52.521607
    }
},
{
    "dep": "2018-11-19T07:53:00",
    "Stn": {
    "id": "vbb_900100017",
    "name": "U Schillingstr.",
    "x": 13.421893,
    "y": 52.520313
    }
},
{
    "dep": "2018-11-19T07:55:00",
    "Stn": {
    "id": "vbb_900120006",
    "name": "U Strausberger Platz",
    "x": 13.432212,
    "y": 52.518029
    }
}
]
}
```